# The last value sent in the Form is added as a comma-separated list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have created a Form with SpringBoot and Thymeleaf.
Binding is working well with @ModelAtribute.
It works correctly no matter how many times I submit.

However, if the session times out after submitting once, something strange happens when I submit after logging in again. Here is the story.

1. submit the string "abc".
2. session times out, so I re-login
3. submit the string "def" in the same form
4. somehow the characters "def,abc" are bound!

Even stranger, this happens across browsers.

1. submit the string "abc" in GoogleChrome
2. session timed out. Next, login with Firefox.
3. submit the string "def" in Firefox
4. somehow the characters "def,abc" are bound!!!

Note that the result of `request.getParameter()` correctly outputs "def".
What's wrong is the result of binding.

test.html

```
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" th:action="@{/form/submit}" th:object="${testFrom}" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{inputTitle}" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('inputTitle')} ? is-invalid">
</form>
```

TestController.java

```
@PostMapping(value = { "/form/submit" })
public String form(@Validated TestForm testFrom, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println(testFrom.getInputTitle()); // "def,abc"
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("inputTitle")); // "def"

    return "test";
}
```

TestForm.java

```
public class TestForm {
    @NotEmpty(message = "not empty")
    @Size(max = 255, message = "size over")
    private String inputTitle;

    public String getInputTitle() {
        return inputTitle;
    }

    public void setInputTitle(String inputTitle) {
        this.inputTitle = inputTitle;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

Can someone please give me a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: `form` and `testFrom` are different instances of `TestForm`. Looks like you have 2 forms which are bound, one is for the request, the other is some shared singleton it appears. Or this code isn't the code you are actually using and is a dumbed down version not showing the actual issue (and I suspect the latter is the case!). Also in your form you should use `th:field` **not** `th:value`. Your form is also weird binding to a different object, than using the value from. All in all the code you posted here is quite messy.

Comment: Sorry, I put the old code.
I've changed "form" to "testFrom".
I'll change it to "th:field" and give it a try.

Comment: Regardless your HTML form is still wrong and referencing different objects.

Comment: I'm sorry my intelligence is so vulgar.
I modified the <form>, but the result was the same.

Comment: You must be keeping state somewhere, so what you are showing here isn't the whole picture.

Comment: I see, but I have no idea what is doing the state keeping. Where is the suspicious part: controller, SpringSecurity, Interceptor?

Comment: Without knowing all the moving parts, and the parts of the frameworks used you modified/extended this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: OK
I'll upload it to github in a few days.
By the way, the values will be retained even after quitting and restarting SpringBoot.
How is that possible?

Comment: What you are describing shouldn't be possible (unless you are doing really weird things). Especially if you state that it also happens when you change browsers (and now restarting your application).